# What did "beep" mean in the 1800s?

Tags: historical-change, onomatopoeia

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beep) the word "beep" was nearly as common in literature in the 1800s as it is today:
[image: goole ngram viewer]
Similar onomatopoeias such as "zap" and "honk" show almost zero usage back then. According to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/beep), "beep" originated in 1927 as an imitative of automobile horns.

How was the word used over two centuries ago? Did it have an entirely different meaning?

Comment: What did Ngram tell you???

Comment: (Actually LOOK at the references Ngram finds.  They're pretty much all OCR errors.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about OCR errors.

Comment: If you're not very familiar with the ngram viewer, under the graph, you should see a label "Search in Google Books:" with a number of links under it.  If you click on those links, you'll see what Hot Licks is talking about (the software used to translate letters printed on a page into something meaningful to a computer is buggy)

Comment: For example, the first book I saw from 1686 (A Treatise of English Particles ... The ninth edition) has a passage that reads: "are ne been facie. Tcrenria may nur hefp шви. '15e ie fain петр .... }попгітпц he mss not **beep** inni antigeen. - àl man newy пишет about his bonitouln affair ému топи “гоп híni as une -nui hei-p leninen. àlgnonmnn ann петр bonei'i". It's actually "In one thing he was not **very** well advised."

Comment: @CJDennis - And if you look at the text, it's reasonably clear that it was the word "very" that was misread.

Comment: @HotLicks Yep! That's why I bolded both!

Comment: @CJDennis -- OK, I missed that.

Comment: (I saw misreadings of "very", "deep", "sheep", and several others.  The fonts used back then were not OCR-friendly.)

Comment: @HotLicks Nothing wrong with the "fonts"! You just need OCR that can recognise those letter forms.

Comment: @CJDennis - Well, the curlicues and jagged spacing make it hard to distinguish one letter from another.  (And, of course, the paper is badly aged and yellow in many cases.)

Comment: @HotLicks You'd be amazed how well machine learning can do certain tasks.

Comment: @Juhasz I never noticed those links before; that's really handy. Also, thank you to those who pointed out which words were being misread.